# c# how to add text line to Textboxes created dynamically on every text change

Tags: c#, textbox, filesystemwatcher

I'm using a `FileSystemWatcher` to watch file text for any changes and display its data in a text box and alert the user when changes are done by changing the form color to red and play a beep sound; the color turns to normal when the user clicks inside the Textbox.

This is my first attempt and it worked fine:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Media;

namespace Breacking_News
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void fileSystemWatcher1_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            string file_name = ("\\\\172.200.10.5\\txt\\عاجل.txt");
            FileStream logFileStream = new FileStream(file_name, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
            StreamReader logFileReader = new StreamReader(logFileStream);
            while (!logFileReader.EndOfStream)
            {
                string news = logFileReader.ReadToEnd();
                textBox1.Text = news.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "\r\n ************************************************ \r\n");
                infoText.Text = ("Last update at : " + DateTime.Now);
            }

            // Clean up
            logFileReader.Close();
            logFileStream.Close();
        }

        private void textBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.BackColor = DefaultBackColor;
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            //FormWindowState.Normal = true;
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

Now I would like to improve on that so each line will be displayed in a separate Textbox. Knowing that I don't know how many lines the text file contains, I will create the TextBoxes dynamically using this code.

I tested this code alone and it worked fine. Each line is displayed in a single Textbox:

```
string file_name = ("\\\\172.200.10.5\\txt\\عاجل.txt");
var linecount = File.ReadLines(file_name).Count();
TextBox[] txtBoxes = new TextBox[linecount];
for (int i = 0; i < txtBoxes.Length; i++)
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file_name);
    var txt = new TextBox();
    txtBoxes[i] = txt;
    txt.Name = ("TextBox" + i);
    txt.Text = lines.ElementAtOrDefault(i);
    txt.Location = new Point(50, 32 + (i * 110));
    txt.Visible = true;
    txt.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
    txt.Multiline = true;
    txt.ReadOnly = true;
    txt.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.Yes;
    txt.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(440, 100);
    this.Controls.Add(txt);
}
```

The problem is that when I insert the second method into the while loop from the first code:

```
while (!logFileReader.EndOfStream)
```

When I run the program, the text boxes are created dynamically for the first text change. But when there is new change on a text file, the text boxes created do not take changes.

Comment: Are you able to change the color of the text boxes w/o the file watcher code?  If not, then it is likely the default text box style overriding your style change and you'll need to set up a custom style on your text box.  If so, then the problem could be that you are trying to change UI from within an event handler.  You may need to post and event back to yourself to let the text changed event to complete before changing its style.

Comment: im changing the UI color, and yes im able to change it when text file change

Comment: Why create a bunch of textboxes instead using something like a listbox to show your data?